# Does not load component until a variable has also been set in useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage

I have a Problem: When the user arrives at the `/chat` path, it should first be checked whether he has fulfilled all the criteria. If not, he will be redirected. If he does, then all his data should be saved from the backend to the `localStorage`.

The problem is that the `ChatComponent` is loaded before the localStorage is set. I have a `localStorage .getItem(...)` in the `ChatComponent` which is null, but as soon as I reload the page the expected value is in it.

Is there a way to load the `ChatComponent` only when the `localStorage` is set, so that I don't have a null value in the `ChatComponent` and don't have to reload the page?

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import { Ellipsis } from 'react-spinners-css';
import axios from "axios";
import Chatcomponent from "../components/chat/Chatcomponent";    


function Chat() {
 
  const history = useHistory();
  const [isloading, setIsloading ] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    filledInterests()
  }, []);

  const filledInterests = () => {
    document.body.style.cursor = "wait";
    axios
       .post("https://localhost:4000/profile/get", {})
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.data.givenname === "FILLER") {
          callFirststeps();
          setIsloading(false);
        }
        else {

          if( localStorage.getItem('getName') === null ) {
            loadUserData();
            setIsloading(false);
          }
            
            
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
        //console.log(error.response.status);
      });
      document.body.style.cursor = "default";
  };

  const loadUserData = () => {
    fillName();
    fillIntersts();
    
    // Only after the variable has been set here,
    // the chat component may be loaded, so that the variables are also set. 
    // What I tried:
    // window.location.reload();
  }


  const fillName = () => {
    axios
        .post("http://localhost:4000/profile/get",
        {
          "field1": "id",
          "field2": "givenname",
              
        }
        )
        .then((res) => {
            if (res.status === 200) {
              localStorage.setItem('userName', res.data.givenname);
              localStorage.setItem('userEmail', res.data.email);
            }
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
        });
  }


  // eslint-disable-next-line
  const callFirststeps = () => {
    history.push({
      pathname: "/first-steps",
      state: {

      },
    });
  };

  return (
    <body>
        {
            isloading === true &&
                <Ellipsis color="#5869FF" style={{left:"50", right:"50", top:"50", bottom:"50",}}/> 
        }
        {
            isloading === false &&
            <Chatcomponent></Chatcomponent>
        }
    </body>
  );
}

export default Chat;
```

Comment: localStorage.getItem('name') === null && <Chatcomponent></Chatcomponent>

Answer (score 0):

Nope, there is no other way to do that, you are handling that as needed. You can changed the implementation details but in the end it will be the same check and if statement for rendering logic.